# How to programmatically adda breadcrumb view to my UINavigationController App?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController App. I want to add a small bar just below the UINavigationBar, around 20px height. y application is almost finished, so I want to rebuild as less code as possible. For example, if I wanted to add a button in the bottom of every view of my application, I can do that by extending UIViewController with a category, and adding a UIButton as a subview of the current controller view, maybe in the viewDidLoad method.

This approach works fine, and so I can add my UILabel to all my views at the top of them. The problem is that it does not TAKE SPACE. It is always on top of my previous views (UITableView...). What is the best way (or just one way) to accomplish such a thing without having to create for example a view with 2 frames, and having all my main views extending it?

I thought of changing UINavigationBar height, but that is definitely not an option.The prompt property of UINabivationBar is just to big (around 30px).

I also tried to create a new view in the viewWillAppear method of every UIViewController, adding to that view my breadcrumb subview, and the original view, but it is not working.

Any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but so you're aware: Apple's docs on UINavigationController warn against attempting to add a breadcrumb control to a UINavigationController bar because if you need to present that complicated a trail of info, "your app is probably too complex and you should simplify" (paraphrased). I know that you're not trying to actually add breadcrumbs to the nav controller itself, but the complexity argument is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd make a new UIView subclass to represent this thing, and embed it on the views of the individual UIViewControllers. They can get at the navigation stack by looking at the UINavigationController's .navigationControllers array, walk that and get view titles, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was doing. But the problem is that if I 'embed' this view on the views of the UIViewControllers it does not take space. Are you suggesting that I modify every nib file for example to add this breadcrumb view? Thank you for such a quick reply btw.

Comment: Well, yeah, I mean, one view isn't going to slide out of the way of another one unless you tell it to. You can do that in IB or in code, but one way or another you've got to move your one thing out from under your other thing. This isn't like making a web page, where things just bump down the page. You've actually got to lay things out.

Comment: Hey Dan, yes, I know that this is not a box model. I know how to move views changing for example frame property. The problem is that when a view has a NavigationController involverd, with his NavigationBar, it is not a view anymore, it becomes a UILayoutContainerView, which is a non documented ios class, and touching its frame causes nightmares... I guess I'll have to do that double view and change all my classes! aaarg!

Comment: Well... That's why I'm proposing that your new UIView subclass breadcrumb be a piece of content ON each view. You can manipulate the frames of elements of a UINavigationController-managed UIView quite easily.